# FirebaseError: The specified authentication provider is not enabled for this Firebase

Tags: android, authentication, firebase

I am creating Android application that using [Firebase Auth](https://www.firebase.com/). But when I add log-in by gmail I got error:

```
FirebaseError: The specified authentication provider is not enabled for this Firebase.
```

Even though I enable Gmail authentication.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmzxZ.png)

Could you explain and help me resolve it ?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530825/im-getting-this-error-the-specified-authentication-provider-is-not-enabled-fo) solution yet?

Comment: *more: I am using firebase-client-android-2.5.2 in my project.

Comment: Try the legacy console at https://www.firebase.com/login/

Comment: Thanks. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me because I was using 2.4.2 instead of their new 3.0.3 sdk.

Basically either switch to new sdk and use their new console, or keep using 2.4.2 but you have the use the "legacy console"

Comment: firebase-client-android-2.5.2. I am new firebase dev. Could you paste link of "legacy console" ?

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/login/ also have a look at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup